# App Billing v3 purchase

Tags: android, payment

In my test app the user clicks a purchase button,and buys an item. When the purchase is done, a textview becomes visible saying "Purchase completed". All good. :). However when I kill the app,and open it again the purchase button appears again....:/. Why is this happening? Google is not very clear on this. Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mService;
ServiceConnection connection;
String inappid = "victory.walkto.testingpaymentsd.productid"; //replace this with your in-app product id
Button purchaseBtn;
Button clickBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

    // first this
    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    // then this
    bindService(serviceIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
    clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add(inappid);
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            Bundle skuDetails;


            try {
                Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3,  
      getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
           // Check response
                int responseCode =  
      ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (responseCode != 0) {
                    throw new Exception("Error");
                }
     // Get the list of purchased items
                ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList =
                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                for (String purchaseData : purchaseDataList) {
                    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String purchaseToken = o.optString("token", o.optString("purchaseToken"));
                    // Consume purchaseToken, handling any errors
                    mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken);
                }
                skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                            purchaseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            clickBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connection != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
  }
}
```

**FIXED**

There was no bug in the IabHelper Class. I had to store the orderId value I was getting from JSON response as a SharedPreference key/value pair.

Something like this.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("productId", sku);
            editor.putString("purchaseToken", purchaseToken);
            editor.putString("orderId", orderId);
            editor.commit();
```

Retrieve them.

```
SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            productId = spreferences.getString("productId", "");
            purchaseToken = spreferences.getString("purchaseToken", "");
            orderId = spreferences.getString("orderId", "");
```

and finally use the if condition to make view visible or invisible

```
if(orderId.isEmpty()) {


                entryFee.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                paymentButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                paymentText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                teamTextField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                paymentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
                        skuList.add(inappid);
                        querySkus = new Bundle();
                        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

                        checkPayment();


                    }
                });
            }else{
                entryFee.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                paymentButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                paymentText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                teamTextField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

The solution was not that hard,but I had to read through the document a lot,use debugger points and that's it:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer here,for those who might face the same problem.

You should store the oprderId and transactionId that come from the Google's server in shared preferences. Only then your program will know when to make the purchase button visible or invisible.

Hope this is going to be useful.

Comment: This is the same answer I posted... This should have been a comment or edit.

Answer (score 1):

Make your code a little less complex. Move the nested click listeners outside oncreate and name the methods appropriately. If I'm right what you're trying to do is

```
onCreate:
    ## init listeners here
    ## then query purchase
    if purchased:
        hide purchase button
        show click button
    else:
        hide click button
        show purchase button

purchaseClickListener:
     make purchase
     if successfull:
        hide purchase button
        show click button
```

[Read the documentation thoroughly before implementing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

- [Querying for Purchased Items](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases): This shouldn't be inside the `onCLickListener` but called from `onCreate` to check if a purchase has been made.
- [Purchasing an Item](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Purchase): This is what should happen when the user clicks the purchase button and you may or may not [Query for Items Available for Purchase](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails) before makeing the purchase.
- After if the purchase is succesful you must [Consume the Purchase](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume). This is inside  `onActivityResult`

Comment: Thank you for the reply,but your solution still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you kill your app it runs onCeeate again, setting it up from scratch. You need to check if it's appropriate to show your button in onCreate, either by using the payment Api to check (if possible) or by storing your state locally in a SharedPreference and checking that.

Comment: Thanks man. That was the best and only solution I found. You saved me from  headaches!

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna try some 3rd party Libs for IAP? I recommend using this lib: [OpenIAB](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB). With this Lib, you can do IAP not only in Google Play Store but also in other Store (Amazon store, Slide me...). Check it for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This was not easy to crack but I found the needed workarounds. Quite disappointed with Google lately, their Android web sites have become a mess (very hard to find useful info) and their sample code is poor. When I was doing some Android development a few years ago it all went so much easier! This is yet another example of that...

Indeed IabUtil is buggy, it does not properly call off its own async tasks. The complete set of necessary workarounds to stabilise this thing:

1) make method flagEndAsync public. It is there, just not visible.

2) have every listener call iabHelper.flagEndAsync to make sure the procedure is marked finished properly; it seems to be needed in all listeners.

3) surround calls with a try/catch to catch the IllegalStateException which may occur, and handle it that way.

May following code help you,

```
try {
     if (helper != null) {
             helper.flagEndAsync();
     }
     helper.launchPurchaseFlow(.....)
}catch(IllegalStateException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Oh man. This is becoming very complicated. The iOS developer did this within 2 hours!!! I am trying to solve this since yesterday. I should move to iOS development at some point. Google is so crap when it comes in importing their APIs in your app. I already imported Google FIT sdk in my app and it doesn't work for samsung S5 and S6.

Comment: at Umang. I can not find any class called IabUtil under the util folder. Maybe you mean IabHelper?

Comment: Yes I mean IabHelper. Find method named flagEndAsync() and make it public. Then, check it again.

Comment: @Umanga. Nothing yet. It was declared as void  flagEndAsync() {...} and put the public keyword  as public void flagEndAsync(). It would not make any difference anyway as void  flagEndAsync()  method uses a default access modifier.

Comment: Before calling launch purchase flow, You have to call helper.flagEndAsync(); method otherwise when you tap second time on purchase button you will get exception.

Comment: @Umanga. Ok. I declared an instance variable IabHelper helper and use it as you said. Now you mentioned something about launchPurchaseFlow(.....)...I can see three launchPurchaseFlow(.....) methods with different parameters correct? I will call them like like.launchPurchaseFlow(???)..What should I put as parameters?

Comment: @Umanga helper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,sku,requestCode,mPurchaseListener);

Comment: Its worthless to put IabHelper's code. Put you launchPurchaseFlow code in question if possible

Comment: @umanga.I put the launchPurchaseFlow(...){...} in the question.

Comment: Everything seems right. Read document once again! You might forget something.

Comment: @umanga. Is it possible to send the IabHelper code in my email please? theoaristi53@gmail.com. I checked the documentation over and over again,but can't find what I did wrong.